# Array concatenation in Python

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and I would like to combine two arrays. I have two arrays: `A` and `B` and would like to get array `C` as follows:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Result array:

```
C = [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

Comment: Usually this operation would not be referred to as "concatenation". The concatenation of `A and B` would be `A + B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Comment: I would call this a good question. The problem is simple yes, but judging from the answers the `zip` function is not as widely used as it should be, so the question already had its merit. Additionally, because of the unconventional description of 'concatenation', googling for it would have never yielded the desired results. Furthermore it was well asked, provided a nicely formatted example and described it very well. That is well asked question, especially for a newcommer! Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: By the way, these are all lists, not arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), the built-in for pairwise iteration:

```
C = list(zip(A, B))
```

Note that you are not *concatenating* the two lists.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, the following solution resulted in C= [('1', '6'), ('2', '7'), ('3', '8'), ('4', '9'), ('5', '10')] which is not correct. I need C = [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]

Comment: @PratheekHb this means you have a list of strings and not ints as you presented in the question...

Comment: Then your input was not what you showed in the question, but `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`, etc. You can easily fix this: `list(zip(map(int, A), map(int, B)))`

Answer (score 0):

Without any dependency:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> C = [(A[i], B[i]) for i in range(len(A))]
>>> C
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

Comment: Incorrect. 1. `len(A)` is not an iterable. 2. If you change `len(A)` to `range(len(A))`, this approach will raise an `IndexError` if `len(B) > len(A)`.

Comment: Corrected with range (misread history). The behavior if `len(A) != len(B)` has not been specified, so nothing wrong in that case.

Comment: Instructive solution. `zip` is, however, not more of a dependency than `range` or `len`. The are all just built-ins.

Comment: The following solution resulted in C= [('1', '6'), ('2', '7'), ('3', '8'), ('4', '9'), ('5', '10')] which is not correct. I need C = [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]